# Displaying different contact number on a website depending on the referrer or google adwords

Tags: referrer, google-ads-api

I am working on a project where I should display different contact telephone number based on the referrer or google adword .

Is it possible to know which adword the visitor searched to reach the website and the referrer?

All the numbers are based in a database. Is there any simple JScript to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late reply...

A simple solution is to pass the phone number through from google in the link that they visit.

Then using PHP on the website

```
<?php
$_SESSION['_phone'] = 'default number';
if (!empty($_GET['phone'])) {
  $_SESSION['_phone'] = $_GET['phone'];
}
?>

<p><?php echo $_SESSION['_phone'];?></p>
```